why do they rotate together?
MovingMark[] mks = new MovingMark[20];


void setup(){
    size(800,600);
    smooth();
    colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100);
    for(int i=0; i<mks.length; i++) 
        mks[i] = new MovingMark();

}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    for(int i=0; i<mks.length; i++) {
        mks[i].draw();
        mks[i].move();
    }
}


class MovingMark { 
    float x=150, y=150, r=1, a=0,b=0,c=0,theta;

    MovingMark() {
        x = random(width);
        y = random(height);
        r = random(1); 
        c = random(255);
        a = random(255);
        b = random(255);
  }

  MovingMark(float x, float y, float r,float c,float theta,float a,float b) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.c = c;
    this.theta = theta;
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  void draw() {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(theta);
    fill(a,b,c);
    ellipse(150, 150,150, 150); 
    //white
    fill(255);
    ellipse(150,150,45,45);
    //line
    noFill();
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    arc(150,150,70,70,radians(280),radians(350));
    popMatrix();
  }

    void move() {
    theta += 0.01;
    }
}                                                                                                                                                      

I wanted to create a class and copy 20 to a random location to write a rotating code, so I wrote and executed the code. I want objects to rotate in one location, but why are all 20 spinning together? I don't know which part to fix. I've modified the code a few times and the result is the same.

Can you elaborate what you mean by "objects to rotate in one location"? Do you want only 1 of the 20 MovingMark to rotate?

@LHY The posted code runs in a Processing editor: https://processing.org/download

I'm not too sure how you actually want the program to work, but I'm assuming that you want each individual MovingMark to rotate on the spot.
To do that, you just need to make some minor changes to your code. The code you have provided is more or less working.

If you look at the documentation for ellipse(),

By default, the first two parameters set the location

Hence, you should not hard-code to ellipse(150, 150, ...) but rather ellipse(x, y, ...).
However, you will find that it will still not work properly because you have translate(x, y) before you draw the shapes. Since translate(x, y) is already providing the offset, the shape's location do not need any offset. So, rather than ellipse(x, y, ...), what you really want is actually ellipse(0, 0, ...). Don't forget arc() also depends on ellipse, so you need to change it too.
Putting it together, your new code should look like
void draw() {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(theta);
    fill(a,b,c);
    ellipse(0, 0, 150, 150); 
    //white
    fill(255);
    ellipse(0, 0, 45, 45);
    //line
    noFill();
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    arc(0, 0, 70, 70, radians(280), radians(350));
    popMatrix();
}

